# ESP32 - BLE connection from Linux

Tags: bluetooth, esp32, bluez

As far as I know, ESP32 is capable of BLE communication.
Mostly done with Arduino, but I'm interested:

Is there a way to attach ESP32 to Linux, and use the standard BlueZ commands (hcitool, gatttool) for managing BLE peripherals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hcitool and gatttool are part of the eight tools that have been depreacted by BlueZ

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617

Zephyr is a small real-time operating system for connected, resource-constrained and embedded devices and I believe ESP32 is one of the support microcontrollers.

In Zephyr's documentation there is a section ***Using BlueZ with Zephyr*** which features a list of the supported tools that have replaced the ones you mention.

https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/guides/bluetooth/bluetooth-tools.html?highlight=bluez#using-bluez-with-zephyr

Comment: Nice resources, thanks a lot. Yes, I was aware of that BlueZ deprecated hcitool and gatttool, just they seemed good keywords for the question.